# running system commands on linux using python?

Tags: python, linux

I'm wondering if someone can either direct me to a example or help me with my code for running commands on linux(centos).  Basically, I am assuming I have a basic fresh server and want to configure it.  I thought I could list the commands I need to run and it would work but I'm getting errors. The errors are related to nothing to make(when making thift).

I think this is because(I'm just assuming here) that python is just sending the code to run and then sending another and another and not waiting for each command to finish running(after the script fails, I check and the thrift package is downloaded and successfully uncompressed).

Here's the code:

```
#python command list to setup new server
import commands
commands_to_run = ['yum -y install pypy autocon automake libtool flex boost-devel gcc-c++  byacc svn openssl-devel make  java-1.6.0-openjdk git wget', 'service mysqld start',
                'wget http://www.quickprepaidcard.com/apache//thrift/0.8.0/thrift-0.8.0.tar.gz', 'tar zxvf thrift-0.8.0.tar.gz',
                'cd thrift-0.8.0', './configure', 'make', 'make install' ]


for x in commands_to_run:
    print commands.getstatusoutput(x)
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?  If my approach is totally wrong then let me know(I know I can use a bash script but I'm trying to improve my python skills).

Comment: Have you looked into the `system()` function in `os` library? (http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)

Comment: The os.system function is not the suggested means of running system calls in Python, and hasn't been for quite some time.  As @phihag answers below, check out the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `commands` has been deprecated for a long time, you should really be using `subprocess`, specifically [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). Also, `cd thrift-0.8.0` only affects the subprocess, and not yours. You can either call [os.chdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) or pass the `cwd` argument to subprocess functions:

```
import subprocess, os
commands_to_run = [['yum', '-y', 'install',
                    'pypy', 'python', 'MySQL-python', 'mysqld', 'mysql-server',
                    'autocon', 'automake', 'libtool', 'flex', 'boost-devel',
                    'gcc-c++', 'perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker', 'byacc', 'svn',
                    'openssl-devel', 'make', 'java-1.6.0-openjdk', 'git', 'wget'],
                   ['service', 'mysqld', 'start'],
                   ['wget', 'http://www.quickprepaidcard.com/apache//thrift/0.8.0/thrift-0.8.0.tar.gz'],
                   ['tar', 'zxvf', 'thrift-0.8.0.tar.gz']]
install_commands = [['./configure'], ['make'], ['make', 'install']]

for x in commands_to_run:
    print subprocess.check_output(x)

os.chdir('thrift-0.8.0')

for cmd in install_commands:
    print subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

Since CentOS maintains ancient versions of Python, you may want to use [this backport](https://gist.github.com/1027906) instead.

Note that if you want to print the output out anyways, you can just call the subprocess with `check_call`, since the subprocess inherits your stdout,stderr, and stdin by default.

Comment: Note that this may be unrelated to the errors you're getting. If you want us to help you with these, *post them*.

Comment: I'll test it and let you know.  The error I was getting is that the folders/commands didn't exist when it was being ran, but after I went and checked they were there.  I suspect that the commands were just running without waiting for the previous one to finish.  I'll try your code out and see the result.

Comment: @Lostsoul Found another problem: The `cd` execution doesn't actually do anything. If you really want to write this short and sweet, use a Makefile, or maybe a shell script with `set -e`.

Comment: Your right, bash might be easier, but I want to learn also. You have got me so far, I'll play around with the code a bit..

Comment: No offense, but I highly doubt you're learning anything useful when you write a Python program that does the job of a bash script. I recommend going through the official (or any other) [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Also, I strongly recommend using at least Python 2.7, and if possible 3.x.

Comment: okay, I'll maybe do a hybird of bash/python..maybe bash for simple stuff like above and python for stuff that requires some kind of logic(if file exists..do this if not do that).  One question, is there performance differences with python 2.7 and 2.6? I use 2.7 on my macbook but the code seems to work on 2.6 so I thought I'd stick with it but many people are suggesting I upgrade, why? I can't seem to notice a difference

Comment: Um, you can do checks like if file exists in bash as well - have a look at [`test`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test). The suggestion to use a newer Python is not because of performance reasons (the creation of a single subprocess will easily dwarf the execution time of your whole Python program), but because useful features such as `subprocess.check_output` require backports for older Python versions. Python 3.x removes a lot of the weird quirks of 2.x

Comment: @phihag okay thanks.  I'll look into upgrading and play around with the code a bit.  I read alot of books on python3 but because many of my libaries were still on 2, I haven't used 3 much. This might be a good chance to work on version3.  Thanks so much Philhag!